# Binding With a TabControl DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I am trying to use `TabControl` to house some ViewModels to Views.

```
    <TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding QuestionIdx, Mode=TwoWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProblemsVM}">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
            <problemSlector:ProblemsViewSelector>
                <problemSlector:ProblemsViewSelector.FreeResponseTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:FreeResponseView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </problemSlector:ProblemsViewSelector.FreeResponseTemplate>
            </problemSlector:ProblemsViewSelector>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplateSelector>

    </TabControl>
```

. . . I've deubgged and confrimed (OnDataContextChanged) that the DataContext of `FreeResponseView` is `FreeResponseViewModel`.  The `FreeResponseView` appears and the Title of the tab is correct.  However, in the `FreeResponseView` I have the following line that does not seem to work.

```
   <toolkit:RichTextBox Text="{Binding Question, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

It is not binding the `Question` from the DataSource.

Comment: Have you looked in the Output window in Visual Studio to see if there are any Binding errors?  You could also use Snoop investigate what the DataContext of the RickTextBox is to verify that it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out . . . the code was not wrong and the problem resides in the `RichTextbox`.  I am using the `Xceed Extended WPF RichTextbox`.  Turns out you have to make the binding Readadble-and-Writable otherwise binding does not work.

```
<toolkit:RichTextBox Text="{Binding Question}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```